# Why is any() so much faster than in?

Tags: python, performance

https://repl.it/@ArmanTavakoli/List-Comprehension-vs-Any

Why is my `any` check so much faster than my `in` check when they are essentially doing the same thing?

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random

input = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(0, 1000000)]

def any_check(input):
  return any(i == 1 for i in input)

def list_comprehension(input):
  return 1 in [num for num in input]

first_start = timer()
any_check(input)
first_end = timer()
print('any_check', first_end - first_start)

second_start = timer()
list_comprehension(input)
second_end = timer()
print('list_comprehension', second_end - second_start)
```

Results of running the functions 3 times each.

```
# Calculated with 3 runs each
# Ratio is list_comprehension:any_check

# 10,000 - Mean Ratio: 17.87
# Example run;
# any_check 1.5022000297904015e-05
# list_comprehension 0.00038980199315119535

# 100,000 - Mean Ratio: 140.76
# any_check 2.020499960053712e-05
# list_comprehension 0.0035961729954578914

# 1,000,000 - Mean Ratio: 3379.81
# any_check 2.2904998331796378e-05
# list_comprehension 0.08528400499926647
```

Comment: Because `any` short-circuits and your implementation does not, always iterating through the entire thing, because you've pointlessly done `[num for num in input]`.

Comment: Note, both of these could be improved by removing the pointless iteration, `any(i for i in input)` is a convoluted way of doing `any(input)` and `1 not in [num for num in input]` is a convoluted way of doing `1 not in list(input)` which itself is an unnecessarily inefficient way of doing `1 not in input`

Comment: Essentially, if you catch yourself writing `x for x in whatever`, stop and think if you really need to do that. Even if it *is* useful, e.g. to copy it into a list, just do `list(whatever)`

Comment: Also note that your two functions do not do the same thing (it's unclear but sounds like you expect them to..?)

Comment: @BrunoEly good point

Comment: @BrunoEly oops - i wanted them to check if True (1) is in the data, I removed the `not`

Comment: @ARMATAV well, your `any` implementation is checking for any *non-zero* number, not just 1. But the other points i've made still stand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh - so it should be `return any(i == 1 for i in input)` - right?

Comment: @ARMATAV yeah. But really, the important thing is you don't need a list comprehension here at all. That is key.

Comment: @ARMATAV In Python [the only falsy number is 0](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) so you'd want `list_comprehension` to `return True in [num for num in input]` or something like that.  That was just an observation, though, and juanpa.arrivillaga's comment stands that the `any` short-circuits and that's the bulk of the time savings

Comment: I see - so basically, if we've got a lot of data, and we reach some check - with `any` we stop and return the moment we find it, but the other way is needless iteration

Comment: @ARMATAV using `in` would short-circuit as well, **but you are pointlessly iterating over the list** so even though `in` is in-fact short-circuiting, it doesn't matter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I gotcha - could just be `1 in input` instead of `1 in [pointless iteration with returned list]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several people pointed out in comments, the reason your function doing an `in` test is slower than the version using `any` is because that function *also* includes an unnecessary list comprehension that needs to iterate over the whole input before the `in` operator can begin looking for a match. When run on lists, both `in` and `any` can short circuit, quitting early if a matching value is found early in the search. But the list comprehension in your second function always iterates over the whole input even if there was a `1` right at the start.

If you replaced `1 in [num for num in input]` with `1 in input`, you'd see performance as good or better than in your function using `any`. Performance would be fairly similar if `input` was a list, but might be much faster for other container types (such as `set`s and `range`s).